# ¿Qué es OData y Cuándo debería usarlo?

Tags: rest, restful, odata

En [OData.org](http://www.odata.org/) dice que es un conjunto de buenas prácticas para la construcción y el consumo de las RESTful APIs.

Aparte de se un conjunto de buenas practicas, ¿En que situaciones debería usarlo? ¿Qué otros beneficios tiene?